# How to change account to write reviews for Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I want to write reviews for applications using another account. In Ubuntu One, it's possible to sign out at will, but I can't do that on the Ubuntu Software Center. How can I change accounts?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to delete the current password for the Software Center and then sign in again and select the "already have account" and sign in using the other account.
There may be a more elegant way to do this as this is a quick and dirty solution but here it is.

Open the dash and start typing "password" , the application "Passwords and Keys" will come up. When you open the application you will see the following. 
[image]
If you click on the arrow the password list will open and you will be able to right click on the password for the Software Center.

[image]

On the right click menu you will be able to delete this password.  As I said above, you will then need to log in using the password to your other account and will have to repeat the process every time you want to switch between accounts.